# Can 又...又... be used to link 2 sentences/phrases?

Tags: grammar

I know 又...又... can be used to link adjectives, verbs, even nouns, as in 又高又瘦.
But then I came across this phrase - 长得又美 武功又高
Is it the same structure? It is, in a way, but actually it's 2 sentences, 2 phrases...
Is it acceptable? Is it commonly used or strange?

Comment: Yes. Perfect for characterizing a person or thing with multiple traits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [又 A 又 B] = [A and B ] or [not only A but also B] when connecting two clauses, but a comma is still needed

Example:

又要馬兒好，又要馬兒不吃草

长得又美，武功又高

> No comma is needed When connecting adjectives or verbs,

Example:

又高又瘦 (tall and thin) connecting adjective A and adjective B

又打又駡 (beating and cursing) connecting verb A and verb B

> [又 A 又 B] can even connect nouns

Example:

又供車又供樓，(我負擔很重耶) connecting two verbs, but it can be reduced to 又車又樓，(我負擔很重耶) which the two nouns are connected by this structure

又吸煙又飲酒，(身體自然差)--> 又煙又酒， (身體自然差)

Comment: I won't say 又車又樓 or 又煙又酒. I will add a verb in between. E.g. 又吸煙又飲酒